# Inputs to the RNN Transducer at test time

Tags: recurrent-neural-network

In an RNN transducer (as defined [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.3711.pdf)), the input to the prediction network at train time is $\hat{Y}$, where $\hat{Y} = \text{blank},y_1,y_2,\dots$, and the output targets are $Y$. (So the network is trained to predict the next label, given the history of labels seen so far.)

At test time, the prediction network does not have access to $Y$/$\hat{Y}$. My question is: what is the input to the prediction network at test time? Is it the output network's output at each timestep $t$? In the paper, it's $g_u$, but it's unclear to me how $g_u$ is calculated at test time.

Answer (score 1):

In test time, firstly, forward the transcription network, then we have the acoustic hidden vectors, denote the length is `T`. To decode, we need to input first blank vector into the prediction network, that means we have the first prediction distribution, denote as `g0`, then we combine `g0` with `f1` to generate the joint probability, then we can apply `argmax` to get the predicted label, if its non-blank, then update the prediction using this label as input, otherwise move to the next transcription output `f_(t+1)` .

For more details, please look at the paper:

[Exploring Architectures, Data and Units For Streaming End-to-End Speech Recognition with RNN-Transducer](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1801.00841.pdf)